# MySQL duplicate column on select from select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a few tables:

- resources (which contains all the posts)

  pid | usrnm | title | link | content | stitle | sdesc | at | likes
- tags (which contains all the tags and an ID)

  id | slug
- retags (which connects the resource and it's tags)

  pid | tid

I'm trying to make a search engine with which you can search by multiple tags, a search value and order the results by newest or most liked.

The SQL I use for searching by tags is:

```
SELECT
   resources.pid, resources.title
FROM resources
INNER JOIN retags ON resources.pid = retags.pid
INNER JOIN tags   ON retags.tid = tags.id
GROUP BY resources.pid 
HAVING
    SUM(tags.slug = 'tag-z')
  AND
    SUM(tags.slug = 'tag-y')
```

How can I apply the SQL for the search value `WHERE title LIKE '%bla%'` and order `ORDER BY at DESC` to this tag search SQL?
I tried select from select but kept gettings errors like "Duplicate column pid", "Column 'pid' in field list is ambiguous" etc

Can someone help me with this SQL? Thanks

I've tried everything in StackOverflow like using an alias for column name on one`SELECT pid as pid_ ...` and even on both selects but I still kept getting the same duplicate column error.

EDIT: The SQL I've been getting errors from:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM resources
 INNER JOIN retags ON resources.pid = retags.pid
 INNER JOIN tags ON retags.tid = tags.id
 GROUP BY resources.pid
 HAVING
   SUM(tags.slug = 'A2') AND 
   SUM(tags.slug = 'AS')
) AS tsr WHERE tsr.title LIKE '%bla%' ORDER BY tsr.`at` DESC
```

This is just one of them, I've tried a lot of different types from other posts and different errors I get from them.

Comment: Do you get the error for this query or for some other one? If another one please include that query in the question. I don’t see how this one would complain about an ambiguous or duplicate column

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen I've updated the question with the query that gave me errors.

Comment: You’ll have to specify the columns you want to get instead of using *. Several tables have column called pid so they need to be specified properly, * will try to create multiple with the same name. In general columns should be specified explicitly and only the columns you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause goes *before* the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT rs.pid, rs.title
FROM resources rs JOIN
     retags rt
     ON rs.pid = rt.pid JOIN
     tags t
     ON rt.tid = t.id
WHERE rs.title LIKE '%bla%'
GROUP BY rs.pid 
HAVING SUM(t.slug = 'tag-z') AND
       SUM(t.slug = 'tag-y')
ORDER BY MAX(rs.at);
```

Strictly speaking, the `MAX()` is not needed in the `ORDER BY` assuming that `pid` uniquely identifies each row in `resources`.

My guess is that `at` is in multiple rows, so you need to qualify the reference with the table it comes from.  Note that I introduced table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.